# How can i specify multiple ports to start appium server in selenium code

Tags: java, appium

So i am trying to start appium using code so i created a bat file with below command
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\Users\Shashank.Shekhar\startappium.bat");
the bat file has content is as below-
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js"
and the port 4723 is hard coded in appium.js file. Now i want to run multiple appium servers from the code.How can i draft the code.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered in the [Appium board](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/8805#issuecomment-313735710).

Try to add --port 4724 after your appium.js

```
--port 4724
```

On my Unix it's just -p 4724